# How to keep a user persistent logged in through my Android application with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm currently using Android Studios for writing an application with the usage of Firebase. What my question is about is how I when I've logged in keeps that status through the whole lifetime of my application until I choose to log out.

What I've done so far in MainActivity

```
/* *************** IN MAINACTIVITY *************** */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Firebase init */
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    rootRef = new Firebase(URL);

   /* Other Android code
      ...                  
    */

   firebaseAuthLisener = new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
            if (authData != null) {
                // user is logged in
                System.out.println("Logged in!");
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
                System.out.println("Not logged in!");
            }
        }
   };
}

/* The Login function gets me to the LoginActivity */
public void Login() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,  LoginActivity.class); 
    int reqCode = 1; 
    startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode); 
}
```

So when calling the `Login()` function I'm landing in LoginActivity,
what I've done so far in LoginActivity

```
/* *************** IN LOGINACTIVITY *************** */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Firebase init */
    rootRef = new Firebase(URL);

    /* Other Android code
      ...                  
     */

   loginResultCallback = new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
           activityDone();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
           System.out.println("Error couldn't login");
        }
   };
}

/* The loginFirebase function logs me into the Firebase */
public void loginFirebase() {
    rootRef.authWithPassword("EMAIL", "PASSWORD", loginResultCallback);
} 

/* The activityDone function returns me to MainActivity */
public void activityDone() {
    Intent resultForMainActivityIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultForMainActivityIntent);
    finish();
}
```

SO as said before how would I after a call to `activityDone()` keep my status as logged in through the whole lifespan of my application until I choose to logout ?

**EDIT:** If someone else find this thread, what I did wrong here is essentially not using the callback, another way to rewrite MainActivity:

```
/* *************** IN MAINACTIVITY *************** */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   /* Firebase init */
   Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
   rootRef = new Firebase(URL);

   /* Other Android code
      ...                  
    */

    rootRef.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
            Log.i(">firebaseAuthLisener<", "[CALLED]");

            if (authData != null) {
                // user is now logged in
                System.out.println("Logged in!");
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
                System.out.println("Not logged in!");
            }
        }
    });
}

/* The Login function gets me to the LoginActivity */
public void Login() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,  LoginActivity.class); 
   int reqCode = 1; 
   startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode); 
}
```

Now is should execute right away after returning from the LoginActivity. Thanks to Frank van Puffelen also see:
[login demo on github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user of your app authenticates with Firebase, the Firebase client stores the token in the shared preferences on the user's Android device. So when the app restarts, the user is already authenticated (unless the token has expired).

So normally you'd only call `Login()` (or show a "Log in" button) when the `onAuthStateChanged()` gets `null` for its `authData`.

Comment: Okej, but when I'm returning from the _LoginActivity_  `onAuthStateChanged()` isn't called automatically when I try this approach. Maybe I should kick start it myself somewhere In the code (what's the proper way to check the users specific resources like UID in this case) ?

Comment: There is no need to start `LoginActivity`. `AuthStateListener. onAuthStateChanged()` should trigger immediately when you register in in `MainActivity.onCreate()`. If that doesn't happen for you, can you set up a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on github?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that once you get logged in to your main Activity store the logged in status in sharedPref as "logged" and move to your main activity.

The next time when the user opens the app check if the sharedPref is set to "logged" and move him to main Activity and on the onCreate() method of mainActivity authenticate yourself with Firebase thus mainitaining the logged status in Firebase.

Hope that helps !!