# How do you keep the user logged in across multiple sessions on Firebase on Android?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I'm currently using Firebase's email and password authentication to login my users.

How do I keep a user logged in across multiple sessions so that if they close the app and come back later, they don't have to login again?

Do I need to save an auth token in my `SharedPreferences` and attempted to login the user via this token when they start the app again? If so, is this the token in the `AuthData` object returned by `authWithPass()` (via Firebase's API), and which Firebase login method should I use with this token?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase already saves the authentication token in the SharedPreferences of your app and restores them when the app restarts.

If you are not seeing this as "the user is already authenticated" behavior in your app, it is likely that you're not [monitoring authentcation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication), but only handle the active flow to [log users in](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-logging-in).

From the [Firebase guide for Android developers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html) (which I highly recommend you read) comes this example:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
        if (authData != null) {
            // user is logged in
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    }
});
```

Also see:

- [How deal with cold start of an app where user has beeing logged with Firebase at previous run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904910/how-deal-with-cold-start-of-an-app-where-user-has-beeing-logged-with-firebase-at)
- [How to keep a user persistent logged in through my Android application with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943661/how-to-keep-a-user-persistent-logged-in-through-my-android-application-with-fire)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I read the guide but spaced out on this part, I misunderstood what it was used for. Thank you for the edification.